# How to render a component using a conditional statement in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, if-statement, jsx

This is my example code.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Navpills from "./Navpills";
import Home from "./pages/Home";
import About from "./pages/About";
import Blog from "./pages/Blog";
import Contact from "./pages/Contact";

class PortfolioContainer extends Component {
  state = {
    currentPage: "Home"
  };

  handlePageChange = page => {
    this.setState({ currentPage: page });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Navpills
          currentPage={this.state.currentPage}
          handlePageChange={this.handlePageChange}
        />
        Based on `this.state.currentPage`, render the appropriate component
        here.
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default PortfolioContainer;
```

The instructions are as follows:

Now add code to `PortfolioContainer` so that depending on the currently selected page, a different component is rendered underneath the `Navpills` component. Example:

- Render the `About` component when `this.state.currentPage === "About"`
- Render the `Blog` component when `this.state.currentPage === "Blog"`
- Render the `Contact` component when `this.state.currentPage === "Contact"`
- Render the `Home` component when `this.state.currentPage === "Home"`

Comment: there is a page in the documentation for this https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html

Comment: Also, welcome to stackoverflow. You didn't really ask a question, but pasted something like a homework assignment? check out this page for how to ask a good question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following syntax to conditionally render a component:

```
render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Navpills
          currentPage={this.state.currentPage}
          handlePageChange={this.handlePageChange}
        />
        {this.state.currentPage === "About" && <About />}
        here.
      </div>
    );
  }
```

But in your case it might be better to use [react-router](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router).

Comment: From what I understand, the code in the question is just for learning purposes. If it is an actual application, you should definitely use react-router.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do it React docs has an example here : https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html

There is also this package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-render-if

Or you can do this terse way of :
{this.state.currentPage === "About" && < About />}